# Performance optimization for retrieving xml table data

Tags: vb.net, performance, sql-server-ce

I have written a code which does the thing as the title says. The problem is, the whole process took 10 minutes just for 1000 records. Here is the code:(Written in vb.net 3.5 and sql server ce)

```
MyConnection.Open()
 Dim count As UInt32
 cmnd = New SqlCeCommand(sqlstring, MyConnection)
 cmnd.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect
 myreader = cmnd.ExecuteResultSet(ResultSetOptions.Scrollable Or ResultSetOptions.Updatable)
 myreader.ReadLast()
 myreader.Read()
 Dim i As UInt16
 Do Until _TableItem(count) Is Nothing
     record = myreader.CreateRecord()
     For i = 0 To 20
         record.SetString(i, _TableItem(count + i).value())
     Next
     myreader.Insert(record)
     count += 21
 Loop
MyConnection.Close()
```

How can I optimize this code for better performance?

Thanks.

Comment: Most likley _TableItem function reads count from the database... Consider adding source of this function to the question.

Comment: _TableItem marks the tag positions to be extracted, innerText will extract the child data, I used to think about downloading the whole data and do the job with stringbuilder function.But how could it be done, and does it going to help? also count is an integer

Comment: I mean the value function will extract the child inner Text as string, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, though I have figured it out myself, I am answering this question regarding to the others stuck in the same problem.

The solution is, actually, to use a for each and a select case(c# switch) statement instead of do and for loops. The code would look like:

```
For Each child as _TableItemChildNode in _TableItem
    Select Case count
        case 0
            record = myreader.CreateRecord()
            record.SetString(count, child.value())
            count += 1
        case 1 to 19
            record.SetString(count, child.value())
            count += 1
        case 20
            record.SetString(count, child.value())
            myreader.Insert(record)
            count = 0
    End Select
Next
```

The code change alone has saved me whole 7 minutes of time. Note that the process takes a long time by default because the records inside the items are very large.

Answer (score 0):

You need to measure and find what takes long time. 10 minutes for 1000 items is very long time, so it should be easy to spot the issue. Use Stopwatch class is for such measurements.

Try first to see if your code is lenear on number of record - measure for 1-10-100-1000 records. I expect that you find non-linear growth of the time (O(n^2) at least).

Measure creation on "record" objects separately from sending data to database i.e. by simply removing myReader.Insert().

Comment: Very strange, removing the insert function has a zero(in seconds!) boost in the whole process. Which means the insert function itself is  very light.

Comment: The most time consuming line is the line that accesses the value property, replacing the property with a constant string saved me 7.5 minutes(out of 10). now, is there anyway to cache the array property as a value or something like that(Note that the _TableItem array itself was not time consuming.)

Comment: Is your _TableItem(index) by any chance using xmlNode.Child[index] (or whatever equalent code)? Getting n-th child of XML node norlally O(n) operation, while everyone expects it to be O(1). As I've said - posting code for _TableItem could have helped....